# Consuming WCF Service with Android

Tags: java, android, wcf

I have the following code in a WCF Service that returns a string, and I’m trying to consume it in an Android app.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace HelloService
{
    public class HelloService : IHelloService
    {
        public string SayHello()
        {
            return "Bonjuor Android from WCF Service";
        }
    }
}
```

I have two problems,

1, I have no idea if I’m even close with the Java due to the try catch blocks. If I have them in the code the app works but doesn’t display the text in the toast or text view, and if I leave the try catch blocks out Eclipse tell me to fix the problem, add a try catch block…lol.

And 2, I have no idea what I’m doing.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.contacts);               

try 
{

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI uri = new URI("http://www.themorningtonpeninsula.com/HelloService/HelloService.svc"); 

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri + "/SayHello");
        httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpget.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

        long intCount = responseEntity.getContentLength();

        char[] buffer = new char[(int)intCount];
        InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
        try
        {
                reader.read(buffer);
                String str = new String(buffer);
                TextView thetext = new TextView(this);
                thetext.setText(str);
                setContentView(thetext);
                Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            stream.close();

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

Can someone please have a look at the code and let me know if I’m even close, or even better point me too, or post some code that does work???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All fixed, the Java code works fine, the problem was my WCF Service needed work. It wasn’t passing back correctly formatted JSON objects. So I went back and and found a great tutorial simple and to the point. I must have completed 10 tutorials before finding this one. Pat on the back for the author.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/RestServiceAPI.aspx

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use another Thread to do Networking task and also you can use `runOnUiThread()` method in order to do the UI updation like displaying your Toast, etc.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are saying as I said this is new to me and just searching the net new to most people. Are you saying I should load the data first and then use it instead of trying to load it and use it at the same time???
I am able to get the default “You have created a service.” Page to come through in unformatted HTML on the Emulator but not the phone, so I am getting something from the WCF Service.

Comment: I think still you should try to get the web service data from another thread and then just check it what is the web service reply.